# How to open a directory and save code in it Gerris in Linux?

Tags: terminal, directory

I have to simulate. but I cannot open and type these codes below in vortivcity directory.I am using remote connection from mac to university machine.

```
[sbalta@dps11 bin]$ cd vorticity
[sbalta@dps11 vorticity]$ 1 2 GfsSimulation GfsBox GfsGEdge {} { 
-bash: 1: command not found
[sbalta@dps11 vorticity]$ 1 2 GfsSimulation GfsBox GfsGEdge {} {
-bash: 1: command not found
[sbalta@dps11 vorticity]$   GfsTime { end = 0 }
-bash: GfsTime: command not found
[sbalta@dps11 vorticity]$ }
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
[sbalta@dps11 vorticity]$ GfsBox {}
-bash: GfsBox: command not found
[sbalta@dps11 vorticity]$ 1 1 right
-bash: 1: command not found
[sbalta@dps11 vorticity]$ 1 1 top
-bash: 1: command not found
```

Comment: You need to enter that code in a _file_, using a text editor, and save that file wherever you want.

Comment: thank you for reply. so how can run it? i am so new to this stuff

Comment: Please [read the tutorial](http://gfs.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial/tutorial1.html).

Comment: Of course I read. but the problem is text editor is saving the file as rtf format. Thanks

Comment: "using a **text** editor", don't use a fancy word processor.

Comment: Could u please specify that. what prog could I use? appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text editor is not a word processor. You need to save your code as a simple text file, you can do that either by choosing "save as text" or the equivalent option in whichever word processor you used that created an rtf file, or just use a simple text editor.

You have not told us what operating system the remote machine is but one (or more) of these should already be installed:

- `nano`
- `vim` <-- NOT easy to use if you don't know it
- `emacs` <-- slightly easier to use (the first time) but still geeky
- `gedit`
- `pluma`
- `kate`
- `nedit`

Just try these commands, the first one is almost certain to work on prety much whatever system you are running. Paste your lines into a blank file, and save it as something (for example `mycode.gfs`).

Once you have saved the file, you will need to run it using Gerris. I have never used this program but according to it's [wiki](http://gerris.dalembert.upmc.fr/gerris/examples/examples/), you should be able to do something like:

```
gerris2D mycode.gfs
```

Comment: @user57606 I was asking about the remote system, not your local one.

Comment: remote system is Linux - the university's system

Comment: @user57606 OK, in that case my `nano` should work. Did you manage it?

Comment: Yes nano works but Sorry I could not save that blank file

Comment: @user57606 use `Ctrl+O` (WriteOut) to save the file in nano.

Comment: terdon thank you so much yes I saved but it is on my mac. How can I see it ?

Comment: I mean where is the nano file can I call it

Comment: @user57606 you need to do these steps on the _remote_ machine, not on your local.

Comment: thank you so much terdon it works I moved the file using scp command. I know u never used Gerris but it should be run when I type gerris2D vorticity.gfs but it does not.. [sbalta@dps11 Desktop]$ gerris2D vorticity.gfs      this is where the file exists..

Comment: @user57606 please post another question about this issue, do not combine multiple issues on one Q&A. Make sure you mention the operating system where you are running `gerris2D` and any error messages you get.